# Creating Geometry Collection from set of Pointz using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a large number of 3D points that are stored as the postGIS Pointz type.
I'd also like to create a geometry collection from these points, but I'm struggling to do it directly in SQL. I've tried the following, but this only puts one point into the geometry collection:

```
UPDATE public.geometry_collection
SET geometry_collection_data = 
    ST_ForceCollection(
        (SELECT ALL object.geometric_point -- this is the pointz type
        FROM object,point,geometry_collection
        WHERE object.pk IN
            (
            SELECT object_pk 
            FROM point
            WHERE point.geometry_collection_pk = geometry_collection.geometry_collection_pk
    )) 
);
```

Is it possible to select pointz and insert the selection into a geometry collection column?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
UPDATE public.geometry_collection
SET geometry_collection_data = (
  SELECT ST_Collect(object.geometric_point)
  FROM object
  INNER JOIN point
    ON point.geometry_collection_pk = geometry_collection.geometry_collection_pk
  CROSS JOIN geometry_collection
);
```

That gets things into `MULTIPOINT Z`, if you want `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z` wrap it again in `ST_ForceCollection`, like this..

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ForceCollection(ST_Collect(pt)))
FROM ( VALUES
  (ST_MakePoint(0,0,0)),
  (ST_MakePoint(0,0,0))
) AS t(pt);

                       st_astext                        
--------------------------------------------------------
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (POINT Z (0 0 0),POINT Z (0 0 0))
(1 row)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but there's still nothing in the geometry_collection_data field ... I have spent quite a lot of time searching the web for examples of converting pointz into geometrycollectionz, but so far have not found a single example.

Comment: @craigL updated check again

Comment: Yes, that works, many thanks Evan! Note the CROSS JOIN is not needed...

Comment: @craigL what do you mean, it's not needed?

Comment: Don't need the Cartesian product of the tables, just the values INNER joined on the geometry collection pk.

Comment: That is true, that's essentially how an CROSS JOIN on WHERE gets planned anyway. Just don't ever do `object,point,geometry_collection` like you did in your OP: that's SQL-89.

Comment: Yeah, showing my age ...